# How to set replacement text of function from token list variable?

Tags: macros, expl3

I'm trying to define a local function with parameters in expl3 where the replacement text of that function should be the content of a token list variable.

My current approach is

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \textbf{##1} }
\exp_args:NNnV \cs_set:Npn \foo {##1} \l_tmpa_tl
\cs_show:N \foo
```

where the expected output is something like

```
\foo #1:->\textbf {#1}
```

but it results in

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@b.
```

How do you handle such dynamic function definitions in expl3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem is the parameter text that must not be braced. You can skip it by using the “without parameter” syntax. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=cs_set%3ANV for examples of usage

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \textbf{#1} }

\exp_args:NNV \cs_new:Nn \foo:n \l_tmpa_tl
\cs_set_eq:NN \foo \foo:n

\cs_show:N \foo
```

The output on the console is

```
> \foo=\long macro:#1->\textbf {#1}.
```

You can also do with the parameters, but it's really ugly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\exp_args_generate:n { NNNV }

\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \textbf{#1} }
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { #1 }

\exp_args:NNNNV
\exp_last_unbraced:NNV
\cs_new:Npn \foo \l_tmpb_tl \l_tmpa_tl

\cs_show:N \foo
```

Answer (score 3):

There is the `p` argument type, which is a wrapper around TeX's `#{` argument. The advantage is that anything valid in the parameter text of a macro is valid here without changing the code.  The downside is that the argument that follows *must* be braced, so you'd either need to change the expansion type from `V` to `o` (which will work because of an implementation detail), or to pass a braced, single-token argument to `V` (which will work because of another implementation detail).

To stick with the `expl3` syntax and have the braces required for `p` you can use `v`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_args_generate:n { Npv } % p = #{
%
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \textbf{#1} }
\exp_args:NNpv \cs_set:Npn \foo #1 { l_tmpa_tl }
% \foo=\long macro:#1->\textbf {#1}.
\exp_args:NNpv \cs_set:Npn \bold text #1 { l_tmpa_tl }
% \bold=\long macro:text#1->\textbf {#1}.
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\foo{hello} \bold text{world}
\end{document}
```