# Should I define expl3 functions with an explicit parameter list when I don't need to?

Tags: expl3, best-practices

I am currently attempting to learn `expl3` and reading [`interface3.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf). Thanks to the argument expansion control provided by `l3expan`, I will not have to define functions with "weird" arguments very often. Thus, I will usually have two options when defining a new function.

1. I can define it using parameter text, e.g.

   ```
   \cs_new:Npn \apply_to:nN #1 #2 {
       #2 {#1}
   }
   ```
2. I can define it using the signature, e.g.

   ```
   \cs_new:Nn \apply_to:nN {
       #2 {#1}
   }
   ```

I would have guessed that option 2 would be preferable as a rule, since it ensures consistency and performance should usually not be an issue. However, it seems that all the examples in `interface3.pdf` use option 1 (except, of course, in the documentation of option 2).

So, my question is: Which of the two options should be preferred? Are there any circumstances under which this changes? If option 1 is preferable, why is option 2 provided at all?

Comment: I tend to use the second method except, of course, for functions with delimited arguments. However it’s just personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

**Option one** is what I generally prefer, simply because of its purity.

When we look at the macro tracing output for `\cs_new:Npn`, we get a reasonable amount of six macro expansions:

```
\cs_new:Npn #1->\__kernel_chk_if_free_cs:N #1\cs_gset:Npn #1
#1<-\apply_to:nN 

\__kernel_chk_if_free_cs:N #1->\cs_if_free:NF #1{\__kernel_msg_error:nnxx {kern
el}{command-already-defined}{\token_to_str:N #1}{\token_to_meaning:N #1}}
#1<-\apply_to:nN 

\cs_if_free:NF #1->\if_meaning:w #1\scan_stop: \prg_return_true: \else: \if_cs_
exist:N #1\prg_return_false: \else: \prg_return_true: \fi: \fi: \exp_end: {}
#1<-\apply_to:nN 

\prg_return_true: ->\exp_after:wN \use_i:nn \exp:w 

\use_i:nn #1#2->#1
#1<-
#2<-\__kernel_msg_error:nnxx {kernel}{command-already-defined}{\token_to_str:N 
\apply_to:nN }{\token_to_meaning:N \apply_to:nN }

\cs_gset:Npn ->\tex_long:D \tex_gdef:D
```

The same log for `\cs_new:Nn` is about 360 lines.

I know people will object "But computers are fast nowadays!" and thus don't care about this. To me the more efficent version still seems cleaner, especially because we get it "for free" by just adding a few more character to the code.

Also, `\cs_new:Nn` cannot be used as a shorthand for a combination of `\cs_new:Npn` and `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`. Trying to define `\cs_set:Nn \apply_to:oc` will fail with

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Function '\apply_to:oc' is not a base function
```

(As far as I understand, this should in theory be possible, as each argument specifier can be unambiguously mapped to a base type. In this case, from `:oc` we could deduce the base type `:nN`, define function `\apply_to:nN` instead, and finally generate `\apply_to:oc` from it.)

**Option two** is still quite handy if we have to deal with dynamic creation of functions. As an example, have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493305/how-to-set-replacement-text-of-function-from-token-list-variable/493309#493309). The problem was to add the parameter text from a token list to the function definition, which could be completely avoided by using `\cs_new:Nn` (actually `\cs_set:Nn`, but the principle is the same).